# show ontology as a tree

Tags: java, ontology, owl

I want to know if there is a java library that can help me show an ontology as a tree in the user interface by taking an OWL file and generating the corresponding tree. I found exactly what I want in [OntologyOnline's jOWL](http://jowl.ontologyonline.org/)  but it's for web application; is there something like that for desktop applications?

Comment: Questions asking for tools or libraries are typically considered off-topic for StackOverflow, since they're not about a specific programming problem, but this is a good question, and you might get better results on answers.semanticweb.com, where this question would be on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the OWL API at https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi. The API provides a means to load the Ontology from files or UIs and a Visitor to walk the ontology.  You can use the visitor to to build your own tree for display purposes - a Swing JTree for example.